# SAP - Business Objects - BI Launch Pad - How to adjust the "auto-sign out" feature

Tags: business-objects

Where in the registry or in the application itself can I turn off the auto-sign off.  Once I log into BI Launch Pad, I do NOT want to be logged off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session timeout for the BI Launchpad cannot be disabled. You can increase it to a very high value (e.g. 180 minutes) if you have admin access. Google "businessobjects bi launchpad timeout" and you will find plenty of resources on how to do that.

Why is it that you do not want to be logged out? If it is just Web Intelligence that you are using and do not want to be logged out you could use the Rich Desktop Client (needs to be installed on your machine). The system will not automatically sign you off of it.

Comment: There are a group of w/s that are engaged in an emergency-response environment (24/7/365) and none of the applications or workstations can ever time out, log off, go into screen saver, etc.  That's my reason for asking for this odd setting! Thanks for the pointers!!